# Dynamically change value & toValue of guides (AMCharts)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to dynamically change the value & toValue field of the guides parameter with a button to reset it. this is my code how i'm trying it:

```js
function changeTresh(){
    var treshhold1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("treshhold1").value);
    var treshhold2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("treshhold2").value);
    
    console.log(treshhold1);
    console.log(treshhold2);
    if(treshhold1 & treshhold2 != 0){
    chartConfig.guides["0"].value = treshhold1;
    chartConfig.guides["0"].toValue = treshhold2;
    
        
    chartConfig.guides["1"].toValue= treshhold1;
    
    chartConfig.guides["2"].value = treshhold2;
    
    }
}
```

This is the code for the button:

```js
<label for="treshhold1">Minimum value:</label>
<input type="number" name="treshhold1" id="treshhold1"><br>
<label for="treshhold2">Maximum value:</label>
<input type="number" name="treshhold2" id="treshhold2">
<input type="button" value="Change treshholds" id="btChangeTresh" onclick="changeTresh()">
```

My function doesn't give any errors but still it doesn't work. i've tried console.log and it performs the function perfectly until the chartConfig.guides["0"].value = treshhold1; line. There it just stops, but doesn't give an error.

Somebody knows what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guides` is an *array*, not an object. Quoting indices on an array is not correct:

```
chartConfig.guides[0].value = treshhold1;
chartConfig.guides[0].toValue = treshhold2;


chartConfig.guides[1].toValue= treshhold1;

chartConfig.guides[2].value = treshhold2;
```

Also note that when updating any property in the chart, you have to call [`validateData`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateData) on your chart object making your changes, e.g. `chart.validateData()`. I'm not sure if chartConfig corresponds to an actual chart object, but if it doesn't, you'll need to access the chart object variable that is returned from `AmCharts.makeChart` and call `validateData` from that variable. You can also access all of your chart objects through the global `AmCharts` object through the `charts` array, i.e. `AmCharts.charts[0].validateData()`, etc.